# Display text from a JSON file in blockquote

Tags: jquery, html, json, getjson

To preface this I don't know too much about JSON and I need it for my first project at work.
What I wanna do is this: I have a blockquote where I want to display text for a few seconds, pause it and than display the next quote. JSON file looks like this:

```
"data":{
    "14":{
      "title":"13",
      "user":"13",
      "text":"Message",
      "profile_picture":"13",
      "image":"13"
    },
    "13":{
      "title":"12",
      "user":"12",
      "text":"Lorem ipsum",
      "profile_picture":"123",
      "image":"123"
    },
```

and so on.
I tried this piece of code to see what will it do but I don't get anything with it:

```
            jQuery(function () {
        setInterval(function (event) {
            $.getJSON('http://thisis.me/ciallwall/htdocs/api/wallposts', function(jd) {
            $('.bubble').html('<p> T: ' + jd.text + '</p>');
        });
}, 3000);
```

})

bubble is the class of my blockquote where i wanna display the text.
So my question is: what's wrong with this code so that it doesn't do anything and how can I loop this text in the JSON file.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i think you are getting json data in wrong formate can u please write code from where are you getting this json data

Comment: {
 "data": [{
  "title": "13",
  "user": "13",
  "text": "Message",
  "profile_picture": "13",
  "image": "13"
 }, {
  "title": "12",
  "user": "12",
  "text": "Lorem ipsum",
  "profile_picture": "123",
  "image": "123"
 }]
} it should be something like this..

Comment: i don't think it's formatted poorly, it's worked for other people

Comment: if the code is working then you can use $(jd.data).each(function(key, val){ alert(val); }) and all the value of json function will be displayed one by one